# keep a div in place within another div

Tags: css, css-position

I have some trouble keeping a div in it place.

My page is divided into two sides. Within the right side I want to have a couple of divs, the first of which should stay on top of it's parent div. The rest should scroll underneath this first div.

I tried it with position:fixed but that binds it to the screen instead of the wrapper div.

My HTML is as follows

```
<div class="side">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis cupiditate a aut totam similique non ipsam, sapiente, nisi possimus dolorum odit voluptatum? Vero nostrum, ab?
</div>
<div class="side">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="box two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div> 
      <div class="box two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is as follows

```
    .side{
        width: 180px;
        float:left;
    }

    .wrapper{
      background-color:blue;
      width: 180px;
      height: 300px;
      overflow: scroll;
      position: relative;
    }

    .box{
      width: 360px;
    }

    .one{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .two{
      z-index: 1;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: green;
      height: 400px;
    }

    .wrapper > div:nth-child(2){
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
```

I made a demo at jsfiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y9nm0j9g/1/)

To recapture, the red div (box one) needs to stay on top of the div while the two green divs (box two) slide underneath them as you scroll them up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting what you mean, just make the .one class fixed and remove the top and left attributes:

```
   .one{
      position: fixed;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oouyu8av/1/

Comment: That was indeed what I wanted. I thought the top and left attributes would work in relation to the wrapper, the same as with position:absolute. The solution is usually 10 times easier then you think once something doesn't work on the first try and you start to tinker around. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, between static, relative, absolute, and fixed it seems that fixed is always the trouble maker in the family—especially on mobile.